# $K:=\{p \in \mathbb R_n[z]: p''(x)\geq0, x \in [-1,1]\}$ closed in $L^2([-1,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials

Let

$$K:=\{p \in \mathbb R_n[z]: p''(x)\geq0, x \in [-1,1]\}$$

$\mathbb R_n$ denotes the set of all real polynomials with degree $\leq n$

> How can I show that $K$ is closed in $L^2([-1,1])$?
>
> Question about $K$: Are the polynomials on $K$ only defined on $[-1,1]$? Or do they only have non-negative second derivatives on $[-1,1]$ (but can also be defined outside of $[-1,1]$)?

The hint is that the set set of all complex polynomials with degree $\leq n$ is a finite dimensional subspace and $p \mapsto p(t)$ and $p \mapsto p''(t)$ are linear functionals on this subspace for all $t \in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

$K$ is a finite subspace of $L^2([-1,1])$, and thus it's closed. In fact $K=\partial K$ since every ball $B_p$ centered on $p\in K$ is s.t. $B_p\cap K\neq \varnothing $ and $B_p\cap K^c\neq \varnothing $.